# R.id returns false

Tags: android

I have just started playing with Android using eclipse. I have been stalled on this one issue for quite a while now, and I have no idea why it doesn't work.

I have started a new app with as little coding done as possible just to see if the issue still occurs. Basically when I am typing 'R.id.' it will come up with the correct list of possible ids for me to access but when I actually try to run them it returns false.

The current one I'm testing has a very simple xml, where one of the ids is 'text'. So when I type R.id it prompts me with options, one of them is text. So i write R.id.text expecting it to return the id. Also when findViewById(R.id.text) it crashes the app with a null pointer exception on that line.

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.reecemerrett.historical.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("ID")
        .setMessage(R.id.text)
        .show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

This code outputs false. I have tried it with many different ids and even with R.id.container.

I also tried removing the whole fragment style and calling fragment_main.xml directly with setContentView().

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextView` belongs to the Fragment Layout ie `fragment_main.xml`.

So change to

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewByid(R.id.text);  
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle("ID")
        .setMessage(tv.getText().toString())
        .show();
        return rootView;
    }
```

Or

As you already tried

I also tried removing the whole fragment style and calling `fragment_main.xml`directly with `setContentView()`.

This will work. Make sure you get rid of Fragment related code like

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewByid(R.id.text); 
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("ID")
    .setMessage(tv.getText().toString())
    .show();
}
}
```

Comment: You're right about putting the fragment_main directly into setContentView(). When I tested that before I was still outputting R.id.text, which evaluates to false either way. So I probably fixed it before but saw that false and assumed it was still broken. So i output tv.getText() like you did and that then I get a valid output. Anyway, thank you very much for getting me to go look again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Remove `AlertDialog.Builder` from `MainActivity` put that code in `PlaceholderFragment` like below

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle("ID")
        .setMessage(((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString().trim())
        .show();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem before. Since your view is inside your fragment findViewByID will not find it for you. Why? I don't know!! But it shouldn't be a problem because you can find this view inside your fragment's onCreateView callback. Assuming your view is a textView the code will look like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content_view, container, false);
    TextView viewText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    return view;
}
```

Normally this would solve the problem because Activity doesn't need to know about views inside fragments. Fragments should handle their affair themselves and talk to activity only when it's necessary. However your activity still can access the this data using Fragment To Activity - Activity To Fragment Communication Technics. I will not explain them since there is a very good documentation on developer.android.com